# Is there a way to wrap generated Tailwind classes under a root class?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I would like to wrap the generated Tailwind utility classes with a class to prevent them from bleeding into consumer stylesheets, like this:

```css
.root {
  @tailwind base;
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
  @tailwind variants;

 .exampleClass { }
}
```

```
<div className="root">{children}</div>
```

However, this does not work.

Could you please give me some advice to solve the issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to generate CSS in two steps.

**Step 1:** Generate the tailwind CSS into a temporary file.

The `src/app.css` file:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@tailwind variants;

.exampleClass { }
```

Generating the temporary file:

```bash
$ tailwindcss -i ./src/app.css -o ./src/app.tmp.css --watch
```

**Step 2:** Use a SCSS file to generate the final CSS.

The `src/app.scss` file:

```scss
.root {
   @import "app.tmp";
}
```

Generating the final file:

```bash
$ sass --watch src/app.scss dist/app.css
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **important** property in your **tailwind.config.js** to set a wrapping class or id.

```
module.exports = {
  important: '#app',
}
```

See the docs for more information:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#selector-strategy

Answer (score -2):

One solution is to add a prefix in `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

This would make it so that the Tailwind utility classes can only be referenced if the prefix is added, e.g. `tw-m-2`, which should (hopefully) prevent any conflicts with the other site styles.

For more details, see: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix